# Help please, Joint 3 tables MySQL (graphically explained)

Tags: php, mysql

Good night,

I'm not an expert in MySQL, I have 3 tables, but I can't find the way to join in a final table in a specific order.

Here are the 3 tables, and finally the last table as I want the final table.
Thankyou

```
Table 1 (Joomla Users)

-------------------------------
|id(K)|username   |email      | 
|-----|-----------|-----------|
|71   |JOHN       |asd@go.com |
|-----|-----------|-----------|
|72   |ANA        |sad@me.com | 
|-----|-----------|-----------|
|73   |PETER      |pet@mine.co|
|-----|-----------|-----------|
|74   |MARK       |mark@nas.co|
|-----|-----------|-----------|
|75   |TONY       |tony@gma.eu|
|-----|-----------|-----------|




Table 2 (ExtraFields)

-------------------------
|Field_id(K)| Title     | 
|-----------|-----------|
|1          |MARRIED    |
|-----------|-----------|
|2          |CELL       |   
|-----------|-----------|
|3          |GENRE      |
|-----------|-----------|
|4          |AGE        |
|-----------|-----------|
|5          |WEBPAGE    |
|-----------|-----------|




Table 3 (ExtraFields values)

-------------------------------------
|Field_id(K)|JoomlaId(K)|Value      | 
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|1          |71         |YES        |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|2          |71         |555-4565   |   
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|3          |71         |Male       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|4          |71         |34         |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|5          |71         |www.go.com |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|1          |75         |NO         |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|3          |72         |Female     |   
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|5          |72         |www.me.com |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|4          |74         |38         |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|3          |74         |Male       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|1          |73         |NO         |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|2          |73         |234-5654   |   
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|3          |75         |MALE       |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|




Desired Resultant table ( i don't know hoe=w to do it)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id(K)|username   |email      |Married |Cell     |Genre  |Age    |WebPage        |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|-------|-------|---------------|
|71   |JOHN       |asd@go.com |YES     |555-4565 |Male   |34     |www.go.com     |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|-------|-------|---------------|
|72   |ANA        |sad@me.com |NO      |         |Female |       |               |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|-------|-------|---------------|
|73   |PETER      |pet@mine.co|NO      |234-5654 |       |       |               |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|-------|-------|---------------|
|74   |MARK       |mark@nas.co|        |         |Male   |38     |               |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|-------|-------|---------------|
|75   |TONY       |tony@gma.eu|NO      |         |Male   |       |               |
|-----|-----------|-----------|--------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: You're a lot more likely to get an answer if you actually list the table name and field names per table in plaintext in your answer.

Comment: please don't link to table layout in bitmaps. It's too complicated to give you an answer this way. Just take the time to type the fields in text form and state which fields you want linked.

Comment: You're trying to make rows into columns. I don't think that's even possible (as far as I know anyway). The way you join the tables, you're bound to get the data in multiple rows per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of options here.

The basic answer to your question is this query..

```
SELECT u.*,
c1.value AS 'Married',
c2.value AS "Cell",
c3.value AS "Genre",
c4.value AS "Age",
c5.value AS "WebPage"
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN extrafields_values c1 ON c1.joomla_id = u.id AND c1.field_id = 1
LEFT JOIN extrafields_values c2 ON c2.joomla_id = u.id AND c2.field_id = 2
LEFT JOIN extrafields_values c3 ON c3.joomla_id = u.id AND c3.field_id = 3
LEFT JOIN extrafields_values c4 ON c4.joomla_id = u.id AND c4.field_id = 4
LEFT JOIN extrafields_values c5 ON c5.joomla_id = u.id AND c5.field_id = 5
```

But his is horrid. You're performing 5 joins every time you run this query, and if you add new extra fields you'll need to add joins.

You could do this dynamically using a stored procedure, but however you do it you'll be asking MySQL to do "unnatural" things.

My strong advice is for fields like these you ought to create a single table and do a singe join to it.

There are cases where it does make sense to have the kind of key/value pair table you've set up - where there are many extra_fields that are very sparsely populated, but for this kind of data (which is essentially user meta-data) I think you'd be better off creating a single table - it's ok to have null fields (they have almost no impact on the size of the DB) and your life will be simpler!

Answer (score 0):

```
**select** tbl_1.id, tbl_1.email , tbl_2.Field_id, tbl_2.Title, tbl_3.Field_id, tbl_3.joomlaId, tbl_3.value
FROM Table1 tbl_1, Table2 tbl_2, Table3 tbl_3
WHERE tbl_1.id = tbl_2.Field_id
AND   tbl_2.Field_id = tbl_3.joomlaId

This would not produce your result but this is the way to link three tables using id fields. 
I hope this will give you and idea . at least.
```